# C++11 Check COM smart pointer for members

Tags: c++, com, c++11, sfinae

I have a bunch of collection-like COM interfaces that I'm trying to write an STL-like iterator for. I've got the iterator working and specialized `begin()` and `end()` to return my iterator. Everything works perfectly! Except, when I try to use `begin(std::vector)`, it's using my very general specialization of `begin()`. Since these COM objects don't extend from a base collection object, I first tried:

```
template< class CollType >
CollectionIterator<CollType> begin( CollType coll )
```

I see why the overload resolution isn't picking the right `begin()` for `std::vector`, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Unfortunately, I don't have a base collection class to specialize the `coll` parameter against. I'm assuming I need something like SFINAE to only resolve these specializations if the right members exist. I tried:

```
template<
    class CollType,
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_member_pointer< decltype(&CollType::GetItem) >::value >::type
>
CollectionIterator<CollType> begin( CollType coll )
```

*(where `GetItem` is a method of `CollType`)*

As well as a handful of variations, to no avail. To make matters worse, these collections are COM smart pointers, so I'm not sure if `GetItem` will actually register as a member of the smart pointer.

Any insights into the right direction would be great, I've been mostly running in circles with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always use some specific COM smart pointer for your tricky collections (e.g. `_com_ptr_t<T>`), you could define `begin()`specialization this way:

```
template<class T> your_iterator_type<T> begin(_com_ptr_t<T>& collection)
```

If this is not acceptable try another possible way (only if you use Visual C++ and don't care to be non-standard) - using Microsoft specific extensions - `__if_exists/__if_not_exists` statements:

```
template<class T> typename T::iterator begin_ex(T& collection)
{
  __if_exists(T::GetItem) {
     return my_collection_begin(collection); // Use custom impl
  }

  __if_not_exists(T::GetItem) {
     return std::begin(collection); // Use standard impl
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `_com_ptr_t` idea is almost obvious now that I see it. Thanks so much, this did the trick.